# How to colour in inside of an object easily?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw the flag of the Philippines using the `turtle` standard library module. I have this code:

```
import turtle
back = turtle.Turtle()
back.speed(0)
back.penup()
back.goto(-255,175)
back.pendown()
back.begin_fill()
for x in range(4):
  back.forward(500)
  back.right(90)
  back.forward(350)
  back.right(90)
back.end_fill()

back.penup()
back.goto(245,0)
back.pendown()
back.right(-180)
back.forward(300)
back.setheading(139)
back.forward(270)

back.penup()
back.goto(-55,0)
back.pendown()
back.setheading(-139)
back.forward(270)
```

I tried to fill in the entire rectangle using the `begin_fill` and `end_fill` methods, but when I try the code I only see outlined shapes.

What is wrong with the filling code? How can I properly fill in the separate regions?

Answer (score 1):

If you slow down your turtle, you'll see that it's looping around excessively, repeating the same path over and over, which makes fills hard to control.

To perform a fill in turtle, the typical approach is to call `begin_fill()`, then outline a single closed, non-overlapping polygon that starts and ends at the same point. `end_fill()` can then be used to fill in the single polygon you've outlined and clear the path for the next shape.

In other words, draw and fill each of your colored regions one by one, rather than attempting to sketch out multiple regions and fill them after the fact, like you might with a color fill bucket tool in a visual paint program. Once you move on to another polygon, turtle's fill operations lose context and will behave unpredictably.

Here's an example of drawing a single polygon that might comprise the top part of the flag:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


t = Turtle()
#t.speed(0)
t.penup()
t.goto(-255, 175)
t.pendown()

t.color("blue")
t.begin_fill()
t.forward(500)
t.right(90)
t.forward(125)
t.right(90)
t.forward(330)
t.goto(-255, 175)
t.end_fill()

Screen().exitonclick()
```

Starting with that shape, you can add code to position the turtle at the bottom of the screen to outline and fill the red region of the flag.

I haven't followed the dimensions of the actual flag, so consider this just a proof of concept of drawing a filled shape to get you started.

Comment: This answer would be improved by explicitly explaining that `begin_fill` and `end_fill` don't work like a "flood fill" and giving details about how the region to fill is computed. OP's apparent plan was to draw the outside border of the flag, fill it all in, then draw some dividing lines and re-fill parts of the flag. It shouldn't be hard to come up with a worked example that fills each region. (Drawing the flag properly after that is a lot more work.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Does the update help?

Comment: It definitely helps, but do you actually know the technical details about how the fill works when the shape isn't simple and closed (and, perhaps, omitting them because you think they'd be a distraction)? I have an intuition that I'm pretty sure is right (because other graphical toolkits work the same way), but I can't cite or prove it offhand.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Looking at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L3383), turtle keeps track of the path of points since the last fill, then draws a filled polygon using TKinter when `end_fill()` is called and resets the path. I don't think the internal details are necessary as long as the fill operation is clear enough at a high level that the programmer can use it properly.

Comment: I specifically meant the semantics of the polygon fill from points - as relates to winding order and such.

Comment: I see. I'm not totally sure of the technical details. I don't think TKinter sorts the path, though, so as along as it's ordered point-by-point without overlaps it should behave normally. If the points are skipped and then returned to, or there are paths crossing the line, the result will probably be undesirable, but not in a way that I can describe other than it'll probably look like a bowtie.